# Error in Capitalizing first letter of string

Tags: java, string, char

A and B are 2 strings to which we have to make the 1st letters of each of them capital and print them in a single line. I have written the below code

```
System.out.println( Character.UpperCase(A.charAt(0)) + A.substring(1)+ " " + Character.toUpperCase(B.charAt(0)) + B.substring(1));
```

The following error occurs :

```
Solution.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println( Character.UpperCase(A.charAt(0)) + A.substring(1)+ " " + Character.toUpperCase(B.charAt(0)) + B.substring(1));
                                     ^
  symbol:   method UpperCase(char)
  location: class Character
1 error
```

**Can someone please explain what my error is and how to correct it?**

Comment: `Character.UpperCase` would not follow java naming conventions. It looks more like a c# function name, using pascal case.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such method `UpperCase`
use below line of code

```
   System.out.println( Character.toUpperCase(A.charAt(0)) + A.substring(1)+ " " + Character.toUpperCase(B.charAt(0)) + B.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method called `UpperCase()` in Character. But there is `toUpperCase()`.

```
System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(A.charAt(0)) + A.substring(1) + " " + Character.toUpperCase(B.charAt(0)) + B.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error code says UpperCase symbol is not found. And it is true.

You should go with Character.**to**UpperCase() method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover if you want to check(if first letter is already capital or not) and proceed..

String name = "Manish";

```
    if(name.charAt(0)>96 && name.charAt(0)<123){
        System.out.println("If block called");
        System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0)) + name.substring(1));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Else block called");
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```